# IIS 7 form input limit

Tags: iis-7

I have a web page that submits form data. Here's the thing, it has about a 100 text inputs fields that accept numeric values.
The problem that I am running into is that IIS 7 is returning a 500 error when the form is submitted. So I reduced the number of text fields to 20, and the error went away.
It seems IIS wants to limit the request size. I have played around with the maxAllowedContentLength setting in the web.config, but that is not helping at all.
Is there any other IIS or .Net Framework setting that I need to change for this to work?
Please help.
My web.config looks like this at this point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<requestFiltering>

    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />

</requestFiltering>

</security>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <remove value="index.cfm" />
            <add value="index.cfm" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>

</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

100 form fields should not be a problem.

What does your form element look like? Does it say method=POST.

I suspect that method either wasn't specified or it was method=GET, which could generate an extremely long querystring and cause IIS to return the error it was returning.

Comment: I am using method=POST.
My form element looks like this:
`code` <form name="doInv" method="post" action="doInventory.cfm"> `code`